# How to Prevent Users from Creating Duplicate Profiles?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a little puzzled about how a primary key works, or in other words, how is it going to be useful in uniquely identifying each record and grantees no duplicates. For example, one user is given a unique `UserID`. How this in anyway will guarantee that the table will not accept the a new user that enters a first and last name that are similar to what an earlier user already have?

Comment: Because the primary key constraint implies uniqueness - SQL Server will **NOT** accept a second row with the same value - it will reject such data. The uniqueness on the `userId` does **NOT** however affect first or last name in any way...

Comment: set the field to Unique...I dont recommend make fname and lname unique..use for that the email or username instead, the primary key is already unique, also in sql-server you have identity column

Comment: Most often the Primary Key of a table is generated automatically by the Database, which increments by 1 each time a record is added.

Comment: Databases, as a rule, don't have a good concept of _similar_. Is Ron John too similar to Ron John Jr? Ronald John? R. John, Esq? Ron Jon? That's part of why it is so difficult to scrub mailing lists clean of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to clarify this in more simpler terms.

`For example, one user is given a unique UserID. How this in anyway will guarantee that the table will not accept the a new user that enters a first and last name that are similar to what an earlier user already have?`

When you setup your table you create a UserID column like this:

`UserID INT NotNull Identity(1,1)`

1st parameter for the identity is the initial start number and 2nd parameter is how much you want to increment each time. You could do Identity (100,10) and that would start it out at 100 and increment by 10 every time.

Set your primary key:

`PRIMARY KEY (UserID)`

When you do your inserts, you never include the `UserID` column because it auto-generates :

```
Insert into names (firstname, lastname) VALUES (@firstname, @Lastname)
```

Now you can have 42 Bob Smiths but each one will have its own unique value.

If the question is wether he or she shouldnt be able to register, then UserID wont help you at all. You can either:

1) Query the database and message the user if there is a true duplicate (check name, address, etc).

2) make a compound primary key of name and address and it will never allow duplicates. (not recommended since you are better off giving the user a friendly message as opposed to a sql error)

Comment: But then, how to make sure that two users (two Bob Smiths) are not claiming the same identity?

Comment: When you set UserID to an IDENTITY column like this `Identity(1,1)` it will never allow an INSERT.

Comment: Oh I think I get what you are saying. Are you asking how can you be sure that the users never duplicate?

Comment: I might have used the wrong term here, identity. I mean what if the same Bob Smith created two profiles. What would be the most plausible scenario to make sure that the same person can't create a second profile, is a composite key a must in this case?

Comment: Aaaah Ok that explains it!. One option is do a check when Bob Smith registers and see if any other of his information matches. Meaning query the db to see if Bob Smith lives on 183 Elm Street in Cambridge, MA. But this has nothing to do with the Identity column or Primary Key.

Comment: Technically you could do a composite key like firstname, lastname, address but even then I have spoken to someone on the phone who married the person with their exact same name.

Answer (score 3):

Having a Unique UserId will not prevent new entries with non-unique first name/last name.  If you want those columns to be unique you will need to put a unique constraint on those columns.  They have nothing to do with the UserId column.

Placing a unique constraint on the name columns would be a bad choice.  There are a lot of `Jon Smith`s out there.

Having the UserId allows you to identify each row.  Example:

```
id   Fname   Lname
---------------------
1    Jon     Smith
2    Jon     Smith
3    Abe     Miessler
```

If you tried to insert a new record with an ID of 1,2 or 3 **then** you would be violating the unique constraint and would see an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you were bound to the whole 'natural keys' idea, you could use an e-mail address.  If you want to get into that argument you are welcome to and there are many supporting arguments on each side.  I personally feel you should have data-only keys, because I like to work directly with data.  Thus a table I designed would look something like:

```
Uid      UserName     Fname    Lname
---------------------------------------------
1        JSmith       Jon      Smith
2        Jsmty        John     Smith
3        JSmythe      Jon      Smith
4        Jabetede     Jon      Smith
```

Forcing a unique constraint on the Uid and UserName.